# Client side MVC framework for use with Unity3D?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-game-engine

Are there any client side MVC frameworks for Unity3D?

Javascript, C# are both acceptable, C# preferred.

Comment: How do you want to use Unity on client side JS?

Comment: I've updated the question. we want an MVC framework for use inside unity, not an external framework that talks to unity. There doesn't seem to be any out there, but maybe a JavaScript or C# framework can be adapted?

Comment: I don't think that you understood Estabans question. Javascript is client side code executed in the browser. Unity runs serverside and is executed in the webserver. So how can you use Unity with javascript?

Comment: sorry, I think I didn't make it clear it was Unity3D, so I'll ask the question there as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game engine Unity is an "ECS" system - it has no connection at all to OO or inheritance.  It is entirely **behaviour based**: the only thing that exists in a Unity scene are `GameObject`, to which you can attach `MonoBehaviour` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MarkUX](http://www.markux.com) it's a MVVM framework for unity (I'm the author of MarkUX).